# Tracing origins of friendly name in SSAS

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I've been given a `SSAS` tabular data model to support and am trying to re-design some of the cubes in hopes of optimising a `Power BI` dashboard.

I want to know if there is a way I can determine the name of the source column behind the friendly name?

Are the columns displayed in the cube in the same order as denoted in the `SELECT` list in the SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DMVs to find the column's source.

Query the $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_COLUMNS DMV. Look for the friendly name of your column in the ExplicitName column. If you have multiple columns of the same name you can look in TMSCHEMA_TABLES to see what the TableID in TMSCHEMA_COLUMNS corresponds to. The **SourceColumn** column tells you the original name of the field. If you need to know the source table/view/query that came from, look at the $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS DMV.

You can query these DMVs from SSMS, but DAX Studio makes it super easy by including a pane where you can just drag and drop them into your query window.

Comment: Thanks mmarie, will give this a try!